# Conditional fields not working with hierarchical select module

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

**Case:** I am using the [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for allowing users to choose taxonomy terms from a particular vocabulary. Based on the chosen terms (deepest level), I want to display a field using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

Currently, the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module is working for simple select widget. But not for [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). Is there any hook or patch available?

Comment: Temporarily I found one solution. If you are not likely to stick with hierarchical select, switch to [Client Side HS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs)
module. This has solved my problem. It works similar to Hierarchical select and also compatible with conditional fields.

Comment: It is always a problem to use Conditional Field module with Hierarchical Select module, if you are not likely to stick with hierarchical select, switch to [Client Side HS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) module. This has solved my problem. It works similar to Hierarchical select and also compatible with conditional fields.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found Conditional field to work with HS but you must enter numeric value of the dependee. For Example if you want to display the field only when term "abc 1" is selected then you check what is the numeric value of that field in the database .lets say the value is 12. That's all you need to enter an its working